# How to break/return an Angular asynchronous call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have the following project structure:
- `PageController.js`
- `BusinessService.js`
- `NetworkManager.js`

In my PageController I have the following call:

```
var getSomething = this._businessService.getMeSomething().then(function(response) {
    alert("my response: " + response);
});
```

In my BusinessService:

```
getMeSometing: function() {
    var user = this.getUserData();

    if(user) {
        var sendPromise = this._networkManager.getAnotherThing(user.id).then(function(response) {
            alert("And another response: " + response);
        });
    } else {
        $q.reject({ message: 'Rejecting this promise' });
    }
},
```

The http calls are being made in the `NetworkManager` class.
So the problem here is that when I have no user data I want to break the call and so I'm using the `reject`.
This returns an error: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` regarding the call in `PageController`.
So, given my situtation, where if I have no userData, I want to cancel the request, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call should return a promise. If there's a user, return the promise from `getAnotherThing`, otherwise, return the promise from `$q.reject`...

```
getMeSomething: function() {
    var user = this.getUserData();
    var sendPromise;
    if(user) {
        sendPromise = this._networkManager.getAnotherThing(user.id).then(function(response) {
            alert("And another response: " + response);
            // you probably want to return the data if successful (either response or response.data, depending on what response is)
            return response.data;
        });
    } else {
        sendPromise = $q.reject({ message: 'Rejecting this promise' });
    }
    return sendPromise;
}
```